# How to read values from ConnectionString config file

Tags: sitecore-api

I want to get values from `ConnectionStrings.config`. Currently, I hard-coded the string in my code which I copied in `ConnectionStrings.config`. Is there a way via Sitecore API to fetch values from this `config` file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**ConnectionStrings.config** is usually for existing Sitecore databases (like the core, master, web etc.) connection details or it can include a connection string to a custom database.

```
<connectionStrings>
  <add name="core" connectionString="Data Source=xxx;Initial Catalog=xxx_Core;User ID=xxx;Password=xxx" />
  <add name="master" connectionString="Data Source=xxx;Initial Catalog=xxx_Master;User ID=xxx;Password=xxx" />
  <add name="web" connectionString="Data Source=xxx;Initial Catalog=xxx_Web;User ID=xxx;Password=xxx" />
  ...
  ...
  <add name="CustomDatabase" connectionString="Data Source=xxx;Initial Catalog=xxx_CustomDatabase;User ID=xxx;Password=xxx" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
  ...
  ...
</connectionStrings>
```

So if you are trying to read connection related settings in your code, you can use

```
private static read-only string _connectionString =
    Sitecore.Configuration.Settings.GetConnectionString("CustomDatabase");
```

---

But if you are just want to read some settings (like some API URL, client ID, Client Secrets) that does not belongs to connectionstrings.config file, you can create a patch file:

```
<configuration xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/" xmlns:role="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/role/">
    <sitecore>
        <settings>
            <setting name="SomeAPIClientId" value="value_goes_here" />
        </settings>
    </sitecore>
</configuration>
```

and you can read in code using `Sitecore.Configuration` reference:

```
private static read-only string _connectionString =
    Sitecore.Configuration.Settings.GetSetting("SomeAPIClientId");
```